# call function based on html dropdown return value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that have 1 dropdown, 1 text box and 1 submit button.

I want to be able to run various .php files based on the dropdown item that is selected. I was 
hoping to use the return value of the dropdown but I have no idea how to do that.
The value in the text box is used by all the .php files that I have in the same directory as the html code.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the selected value? It would be whatever your selectbox name is: `$_POST['select-name']` will pull the selected value. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to read the selected value, and then run a piece of code from a different file depending on the value, is that right?And is the text box relevant?

Comment: Is there a syntax that reads something like this. If return_value == a then do this ? I'm new to html transitioning from java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to run a certain php file based on the drop down selection. You can simply **include** the php file you want to "run". 
Let's say you have 2 "runnable" php files: a.php and b.php

a.php

```
// a.php
echo 'a says '.$_POST['text'];
```

b.php

```
// b.php
echo 'b says '.$_POST['text'];
```

selector.php (where the form POST data goes)

```
<?php
// select.php
include $_POST['selection'];
?>
```

and the HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="selector.php">
some text: <input type="text" name="text" /><br/>
select function:
<select name="selection"><option value="a.php">A</option><option value="b.php">B</option></select>
</form>
```

This is just an example, make sure to restrict the files you can include somehow for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i understand correctly, one way would be to do something like:

```
include 'fileWithFunctions.php';

$selection = $_POST['drop-down-selection'];

if($selection == "option1")
    firstFunction();
else if($selection == "option2")
    secondFunction();
//and so on
```

Should work, I'm a little out of touch with PHP.

**Update:** If you're getting error messages before you click the submit button, then you have to put this inside an if statement checking if the button has been pressed.